# Make copy to my account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a few shared Worksheet with a set of scripts. When the user finishes his/her work, I want them to click a button to execute the script. 
The first step, is to make a backup copy of the w/s. Here is the problem, it copies to HIS/HER account. 
That's wrong. I want it to my  account.

`ss.copy(this+"bkp")`

what do I have to do to make this copy be dumped on **my** account?

Answer (score 0):

Make the script run as you, instead of the user. When up publish the app select the execute as me function.

Comment: it did not work. Actually, I tried both cases, ONLY MYSELF and ANYONE
In both cases I executed the script with the user's account and it copies the backup to his account. 
Is it because I'm not running as a Google App?
this are just WS with scripts. Did not make the move to the Apps cause of this same reason. I need to be able to control where the information moves.